# Mongoose aggregate, Match, Count, Group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am trying to send a list of total paid and unpaid client with ***count along with data*** from my node API.
In mongoose method, I am stuck at thinking how to go further.

can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this?

```
router.get("/", ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
   Loan.aggregate([
     {
       $match: {
         ePaidunpaid: "Unpaid"
      }
     }
   ]).then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     res.render("dashboard", { admin: req.user.eUserType, user: req.user,data:data });
   });
});
```

**Loan Model:**

```
const Loan = new Schema({
  sName: { type: String },
  sPurpose: [String],
  sBankName: String,
  sBranchName: [String],
  nTotalFees: { type: Number },
  ePaidunpaid: { type: String ,default:'Unpaid'},
  sCashOrCheque: { type: String },
});
```

**Outcome:**
**Details of a user with a count of paid and unpaid clients**

```
[
  Paid:{
    // Paid users
},

  Unpaid:{
    // Unpaid Users
  },
]
```

Comment: Kindly post your the shape of result that you are expecting out of your query.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh Look at the edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well in that case, try this -

```
Loan.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$ePaidunpaid",
      data: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
]);
```

Output would be something like this -

```
{
  "_id": "Paid",
  "data": [
    // All the documents having ePaidunpaid = Paid
    { _id: "asdasd123 1eqdsada", sName: "Some name", // Rest of the fields },
    { _id: "asdasd123 1eqdsada", sName: "Some name", // Rest of the fields }
  ],
  count: 2
},
{
  "_id": "Unpaid",
  "data": [
    // All the documents of having ePaidunpaid = Unpaid
    { _id: "asdasd123 1eqdsada", sName: "Some name", // Rest of the fields },
    { _id: "asdasd123 1eqdsada", sName: "Some name", // Rest of the fields }
  ],
  count: 2
},
```

**Explanation**

First stage of the pipeline `$group` groups all the documents according to `ePaidunpaid`field which only have two values `Paid` or `Unpaid` thus rendering only two documents respectively.

Next step is to accumulate original data (documents) being grouped together. This is achieved using `$push` accumulator on data field, pushing `$$ROOT` which effectively references the document currently being processed by pipeline stage.

Since you needed count of all paid and unpaid users hence a `$sum` accumulator to count all the items in each group.